# Javascript move div onClick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, move

I'm trying to get a div `#sidebar` that rests above my main `#stream` div to move from position `left: 565px;` to position `left: 0px;` onClick of one image in the `#sidebar` div (the red arrow in the images below), and do the reverse onClick of the same image. I know I have to use JavaScript, but I have no idea what the code would be. If possible, I would like to animate the div move too.

The pre-clicked state (the arrow will be my link):
[image: main view]

The post-clicked state:
[image: app view]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to animate it using animate have a look at this. It should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/5/embedded/result/ - Full screen result

http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/5/ - source code

So what I simply did was this:

```
$(function()
{
  var expanded = false;
  $('#sidebar').click(function()
                      {
                          if (!expanded)
                          {
                              $(this).animate({'left' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                              expanded = true;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             $(this).animate({'left' : '565px'}, {duration: 400});
                              expanded = false;
                          }
                      });
 });
```

This is probably the simplest way of doing it via animation. Duration is set to 400 so it will take 0.4 seconds to animate. Adjust as you please.

This script should be executed as soon as you load the page to ensure that the expand works. You will want to create `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag in the header and put the code there.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, your JSFiddle looks exactly as I imagined. But I can't get it to work in my code - I've called jQuery, put it in the <head> as you suggested, tagged my div up with id="sidebar" class="sidebar", and I still can't get the div and the js to connect. Can I have a table in the div? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Yeah you definitely can, in the fiddle I have a float right applied to the sidebar, I'll post the link to source code in the answer

Comment: @OliverW Here you go, source code in jsfiddle is posted in the answer, just double check the css in sidebar etc (float right, position relative), if it still doesnt work then please post your css and code sample and ill fix it for you

Comment: Thanks for your help! I pasted it in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iobjf), because it was quite long, and the JS works perfectly... but the same code doesn't in Safari or Chrome, standalone. Pasted back into Dreamweaver, still no luck. This is odd...

Comment: @OliverW I tried that in Codepen in Chrome and it works perfectly here, did you try to use javascript debugger and console to see whats going wrong?

Comment: It works for me in Codepen, but not when I run it from my computer i.e. offline. Thanks for your help again, I'll accept the answer even though I haven't got it running perfectly.

Comment: @OliverW thanks a lot, did you try openning the console and trying to tigger the behaviour and see if any errors araise? Does js work at all offline on your pc?

Comment: It doesn't work offline - no idea why, but I got it working online! [Here](http://streamerforipad.webs.com/Stream/Stream.html) (the viewport size would be 640px X 855px.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sidebar').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({"left": "0"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery uses toggle to handle this. It works better than a regular "animate" because it combines the hide and show into one function (toggle).

You might need to do some tweaking to fit your needs but this should get you started:http://jqueryui.com/toggle/