# Click image to move div up, then click again to move it back using jQuery

Tags: html, click

I have a div that is 300px from the top, and an up arrow image on top of the div.

I want users to click on the up arrow image, making this div go up 300px, then the up arrow image changes into a down arrow image, then when users click on the down arrow image, this div goes back down 300px to it's original location.

I'm looking to do this with jQuery.

using a response, this is what my markup looks like now:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.container img').click(function() {
        $('.container').animate({top:-276});
    });
    $('.container img').click(function() {
        $('.container').animate({top:0});
    });
});
```

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-top:300px;
  height:800px;
  padding:50px;
  position:relative;
}
 
.container img{
  position:absolute;
  top:-22px;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="container">

 <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" />

 <p>some text here</p>
 
</div>
  
</body>
```

The div is just moving up and down without stopping at the top.

Also, how do I get a the up arrow to change to down arrow on first click? then back again to up arrow on second click?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`jQuery.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) triggered by the [`jQuery.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Like this but with 2 states, toggling from one to the other:

```
$(function() {
    $('#arrow').click(function() {
        $('#thediv').animate({top:300});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
  var expanded = false;
  $('#sidebar').click(function()
                      {
                          if (!expanded)
                          {
                              $(this).animate({'left' : '0px'}, {duration : 400});
                              expanded = true;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             $(this).animate({'left' : '565px'}, {duration: 400});
                              expanded = false;
                          }
                      });
 });
```

You can check this link below. May be it can help you to find solution.
link:-[Javascript move div onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038989/javascript-move-div-onclick)